# How can I tell how far into a git rebase I am when resolving conflicts?

Tags: git, conflict, rebase

I am rebasing in git and am encountering many conflicts.  I address each one and do `git rebase --continue`, only to be met with the next conflict.  How can I see how close I am to successfully completing the rebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get a measure of how far you have to go, but it lists how many commits into the rebase you are. In the error output is a line that looks like

```
Patch failed at 0003 <commit message>
```

0003 means you're three commits into the rebase.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, does this mean I've applied three of my commits, or three remote ones?  If its mine I suppose I can use that and how many commits I was ahead to get a sense of progress.

Comment: @Zugwalt: a rebase applies to a certain ordered list of commits. The 3 means you're on the third in the list. It's not a matter of "mine" vs. "remote". Try reading the first part of the description of [git-rebase](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html). It might take a few times through, but if you can grasp the concept, it will help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Ok I think I get it and can figure out progress using a combination of that number and git log statements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can see a list of patches here:

```
.git/rebase-apply/[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about seeing how many conflicts are already resolved, I have I usually do a quick

```
$ git diff
```

while doing a rebase. Conflicting parts will not be staged yet (assuming you are using `git mergetool`).

Alternatively you could also directly grep for the conflict markers.

If you want to know how many commits were already applied, just use

```
$ git log REBASE_BASE..
```

where `REBASE_BASE` is the commit you are rebasing onto.

Answer (score 0):

The text file .git/sequencer/todo will show you the next commits to be rebased or cherry-picked.

Also, in Windows, the Git Bash shell has the rebase progress status in the prompt in the following format:
`(branch-name|REBASE 1/10)`

From Powershell I can get to Git Bash with this command:
`sh --login`

Comment: I dont see that file anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I found `.git/rebase-merge/done` and `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` here, on git version 2.41.0.

I am not sure if these are considered implementation details or part of git's public interface but, if you have them, you can try to count the number of lines in those files to get an impression of how far along the rebase is. For instance, if you have `wc`:

```
$ wc -l .git/rebase-merge/{done,git-rebase-todo}
   95 .git/rebase-merge/done
  251 .git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
  346 total
```

These may include actions beyond mere commit picks, but those are arguably part of the progress as well. Some empty lines add a little distortion. They can be filtered with `grep` before counting.